# Are table names in query case-insensitive?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have read the following [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113317). They have quoted that,

> SQL Server is a case-sensitive back-end application. This means that a
>   table named "addr" is distinguished from a table named "ADDR."
>   However, because Microsoft Query is an MS-DOS-based application, it is
>   unable to distinguish cases; therefore, Microsoft Query views "addr"
>   and "ADDR" as the same file.

Now I wanted to know what to they mean by `case-sensitive back-end application`? Is it safe to use the `query` with `case-insensitivity`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the default collation of the database whether object names are treated as case sensitive or not. That document is very old BTW!

Comment: To be safe, you should always use the correct case for object and column names. You never know when your code or your database will be changed or migrated to a case-sensitive collation. In fact I often advocate developing on a case-sensitive collation to help prevent preventable errors later.

Comment: That article is very old (the information is from around 1995) and is now incorrect.

Comment: You've missed their *Retired KB Content Disclaimer*: `This article was written about products for which Microsoft no longer offers support. Therefore, this article is offered "as is" and will no longer be updated.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SQL Server with default collation will return you the same result, doesn't matter which case you use for your query.

Collation can be set at various levels

1. Server
2. Database
3. Column

For more info can be found out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391(v=SQL.100).aspx)

Please check **Applies To** section of the article you referenced. KB article applies to product from Microsoft for which they no longer provide any support.

Comment: Quite irrelevant based on the quoted KB article, sorry